# Should this date predicate work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate

Is there any reason this search predicate should not work on iOS ?  The same seems to work fine on OS X.  I checked and date.description returns a string in this format '2013-08-28 23:18:16 +0000'.  I am trying to implement a UISearchBar to filter results and would like the user to be able to type in any part of the date.

```
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date.description contains %@", self.searchString]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If it works it's coincidence. According to the documentation [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description) of `NSDate` is for debugging purposes only.

Turn your NSString into a NSDate and write your predicate like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ";

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:self.searchString];
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", date];
```

---

Edit: After reading your question again this answer is probably not very helpful.
I would try to save the result of `[df stringFromDate:date];` for each object somewhere. Then you should be able filter with a `contains` predicate. But you must not rely on `description`.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing it the hard way, which is traversing the hierarchy of objects and using the NSDateFormatter to get the date string and then comparing it to what the user typed in.  I can't convert what the user types to a date because they could enter any string to search any fields.